What standard defines EUI-64?
I'm trying to understand why does creating modified EUI-64 format interface identifiers from IEEE 802 48-bit MACs incorrectly use 0xFFFE and why should've it used 0xFFFF.
I belive there should be a sandard for EUI-64, but I was unable to find it.
What I found is another Network Engineering question titled Why the FF:FE in EUI-64? with a single answer citing a Cisco Community post with the following explanation:

0xFFFE was chosen by the IEEE as a reserved value to reflect the fact that a given address is in the modified EUI-64 format.

However I was unable to find any standards document that support this claim.
The first RFC describing IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture (RFC 1884) on page 7 describes address generation from 48bit MACs as-is, so no EUI-64 mentions there.
The first RFC to mention EUI-64 is 2373 (which obsoleted 1884), in this document there is APPENDIX A : Creating EUI-64 based Interface Identifiers, with the relevant part:

Links or Nodes with IEEE 802 48 bit MAC's
[EUI64] defines a method to create a EUI-64 identifier from an IEEE 48bit MAC identifier.  This is to insert two octets, with hexadecimal values of 0xFF and 0xFE, in the middle of the 48 bit MAC (between the company_id and vendor supplied id).

The reference marked for EUI64 is Guidelines for 64-bit Global Identifier (EUI-64) Registration Authority which says

Restricted and encapsulated values
To support encapsulation of EUI-48 values within a small subset of the EUI-64 values, the first four digits of the manufacturer's extension identifier shall not be FFFF16 or FFFE16. Thus, the 64-bit values of the following form (where 'x' is a arbitrary hexadecimal digit) are never-assigned EUI-64 values:
ccccccFFFEeeeeee16 (an EUI-48 extension)
xxxxxxFFFFxxxxxx16 (reserved by IEEE/RAC)
The letters 'c' and 'e' represent hexadecimal digits and show how the EUI-48 value can be unambiguously encapsulated within the EUI-64 value; the 'c' and 'e' digits represent the company_id and extension-identifier portions of the EUI-48 value respectively.

My problem with this answer is it's only a guideline not a standard (or should we look at it like one?), has no explanation why those values were choosen, but most importantly RFC 4291 (which obsolted 3513 and which obsoleted 2373) has a note added on page 22 saying

[EUI-64] actually defines 0xFF and 0xFF as the bits to be inserted to create an IEEE EUI-64 identifier from an IEEE MAC-48 identifier. The 0xFF and 0xFE values are used when starting with an IEEE EUI-48 identifier. The incorrect value was used in earlier versions of the specification due to a misunderstanding about the differences between IEEE MAC-48 and EUI-48 identifiers.

This made me question what's the difference between EUI-48 and MAC-48? Which standard describes these? Which standard describes the conversion that caused the misunderstanding?
Also way before 2006 - when the RFC in question was made - the referenced guideline for EUI64 reported 404 errors for archive.org, so they couldn't base that note on it.
Also if the reason for flipping the U/L bit is to make it possible to use the :: sorthand more efficiently and to get prettier addresses in the resulting IPv6 addresses for locally administered MACs (Source: Page 9 of RFC 2373) then using 000016 would've made much more sense; but they probably obeyed to some standard?!
Other documents I found
Guidelines for Use of Extended Unique Identifier (EUI), Organizationally Unique Identifier (OUI), and Company ID (CID)
on page 15 says

Some standards have described how an EUI-48 value could be mapped to an
EUI-64, as follows: [...]
In other words, the EUI-64 value was generated by inserting either the value
FF-FEhex or the value FF-FFhex in between eui48[2] and eui48[3].

eui64.pdf this has mentions of both values in the correct context MAC-48/EUI-48 but still doesn't give clear answers as to why those values were choosen?
EDIT:
Why the extra bytes were added to the manufacturer's space?
This was one of my original questions, but after applying some common sense I belive it's because OUIs are still 24 bits in EUI64 so it makes sense to keep it when mapping IEEE 802 48-bit MACs. Then it also makes sense to place it in the first two MSBs of the manufacturers' space since it's a serial value.
Why does IPv6 addressing follows adding those two bytes?
This was another question, but as I spent quite a few hours by now reading through all the docs and piecing them together I think it's because getting EUI64 from MACs is only one way of getting an EUI64, it can also be from the manufacturer or it can be a locally administered EUI64 in which case there could be an EUI64 like 02:00:00:00:00:00:00:01 and when this is converted to IPv6 interface ID it becomes ::1 which actually makes perfect sense.
Looks like I managed to figure out answers to my original questions, but I'd like to know if my answers are indeed correct and they also followed the same tought process or is it just a coincidence. So I'm still looking for the original IEEE standard/guideline.

"Also if the reason for flipping the U/L bit is to make it possible to use the :: sorthand more efficiently and to get prettier addresses in the resulting LLAs for locally administered MACs then using 000016 would've made much more sense; but they probably obeyed to some standard?!" This is often misinterpreted. You set the bit for a modified EUI-64 because it is locally derived. People often assume you flip it, but a locally assigned EUI-48 should already have the bit set, and you would not clear it (flip), but leave it set.

@RonMaupin I added the reference to that claim.

That is an obsolete RFC. The current RFC is 4291, and it clearly shows that bit being set to 1.

That reasoning is still present in 4291 and the example provided in the appendix is not consistent with the text explaining it so I belive that's a typo there.

@Zac67 Well the often vague wording and lack of details made me think there are more detailed documents. Also after a bit more thinking I belive they added the extra bytes to the manufacturers' space so the mapped address belongs to the same company id. And the values are just arbitrary bytes choosen by an IEEE employee?!

@NoelNemeth IEEE define standards by task force, work group or committee, formed by their members. There's no single person doing it (and few employees to start with).

The fact is that the modified EUI-64 is a locally derived address, and it needs to have the U/L bit set to indicate that. If you take a local address and flip the bit, you are saying that it is now a global address. That is not the intention of setting that bit. The wording assumes it is a global address, then you do "flip" the bit, but if you are starting with a local address, you do not flip the bit.

@Zac67 Well what I meant is someone came up with a random value and everyone agreed on that. And I'm still not sure how to find the original IEEE document for EUI64, since there are guidelines - without numbers - and standards - with numbers e.g. 802-2001 and the only detailed guideline I found is from 2017 but rfc 2373 already referenced it in 1998.

@RonMaupin We might be talking past each other, I know that going MAC -> EUI64 only inserts 2 bytes, but then going from EUI64 -> IPv6 Interface ID (aka modified EUI64) involves the flipping of u/l (as described in rfc 4291 section 2.5.1.) since as an interface ID it no longer has a special meaning.

Forget about my earlier comments - see the answer.

EUI-64 is defined in IEEE 802 clause 8, which also describes converting between EUI-48 and EUI-64 in clause 8.3. Looking for an RFC doesn't help as the IETF sets standards for IP's network layer and upwards, but not for the link layer.
You can get 802-2014 here (free after registration).

Oh, so I accidentally found it, but I just looked at the contents saw no mention of EUI and went on... (I started my journey from the IPv6 RFC and didn't find any more matching tags for the question, that's why only the rfc is there.)

Am I right that the actual conversion from EUI-48 to 64 is described in either IEEE Std. 802.1D or 802.1Q (both paywalled)? Because section 8.3. only mentions these and the fact that you can't go from 64 to 48.

You can get all current 802 standards free from https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/browse/standards/get-program/page/series?id=68, including 802.1Q. 802.1D is long obsolete and not free any more.
